# Sql query using wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Table :** City

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| aaa   |
+-------+
| bbb   |
+-------+
| iii   |
+-------+
| uuu   |
+-------+
```

Need to output results with city name starts with vowels (a,e,i,o or u)

My Query:-

```
Select Name 
from City
 where Name like 'a%' 
     or Name like 'e%'
     or Name like 'i%'
     or Name like 'o%'
     or Name like 'u%'
```

It gives desired results though,is there any other way to use wildcards more better in such case?

Comment: Where Left(Name, 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') would prevent the need for wildcards instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [set notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
where Name like '[aeiou]%'
```

There is also a range notation `'[a-z]'` if you want to match any character in a contiguous range but that doesn't help in your case.